# Fill a list of lists in a for loop with the results of a dot product

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I'm trying to fill a list of lists with the result of a dot product. The idea is that `df1` is updated in each `j` iteration so that `data_structure` takes the new values of `df1` when the append method is applied, and also store the result of such dot product into `states_container` and so on for each iteration of `j`. Here's what I've code so far without reaching the result I'm expecting:

```
features1 = {'x1': [5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4],
        'x2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        'x3': [9,10,11,12,5,6,7,8],
        'x4': [13,14,15,16,9,10,11,12]
        }
features0 = {'x0':[9,10,11,12,5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(features1, columns = ['x1', 'x2','x3','x4']).to_numpy()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(features0, columns = ['x0']).to_numpy()
coeff = np.array([[ 0.2,  0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1]])

data_structure = []
current_state = []
states_container = [[] for k in range(3)]

for j in range(3):
                  
    for i in range(len(df)):
        
        # Dataframe constructor according to forecasting strategy
        if (i < len(df) - 1):
            
        # Create the data structure
            data_structure.append(np.append(df1[i], df[i+1])) 
     
        # Using the data structure, apply the dot product
            current_state.append(np.dot(coeff, data_structure[i]))
            
    df1[j] = np.stack(current_state[j])
    
    states_container[j].append(current_state)

np.stack(states_container)
```

This is the result I'm getting from the above code:

```
array([[[[10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2],
         [10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2],
         [10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2]]],


       [[[10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2],
         [10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2],
         [10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2]]],


       [[[10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2],
         [10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2],
         [10. ],
         [11.5],
         [13. ],
         [ 7.3],
         [ 7.2],
         [ 8.7],
         [10.2]]]])
```

I did by hand the dot product and this is the result I am expecting in the `states_container` object:

```
array([[[[10.])
   [11.5],
   [13.],
   [7.3],
   [7.2],
   [8.7],
   [10.2]]],
[[[10.2],
   [11.8],
   [13.39],
   [6.36],
   [7.64],
   [9.24],
   [10.84]]],
[[[10.24],
   [11.86],
   [13.478],
   [6.172],
   [7.728],
   [9.348],
   [10.968]]]]
```

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do regarding updating df1. But your code can be shortened to:

```
states_container = []

for j in range(3):
    dfx = df.shape[0]
    data_structure = [np.append(df1[i], df[i + 1]) for i in range(dfx - 1)]
    current_state = np.stack([np.dot(coeff, data_structure[i]) for i in range(dfx - 1)])

    #INSERT YOUR UPDATE DF1 HERE
    states_container.append(current_state)
```

About updating df1, your question is a bit ambiguous since current_state has a shape of `(7, 1)` while df1 has a shape of `(8, 1)`. The code above results in the array shape that you want(but three repeated numpy arrays as I did not update df1).

Could this be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Thank you @lock_inside, your code was very useful. I just had to make some small changes. I understand your point regarding the shape of ```current_shape``` against ```df1```, but the nature of the routine I'm working with, requires me to do that. I appreciate your help and your feedback regarding what an XY problem is. Sorry for the confusion.